# Error running the converter as Azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, nreco

I created an Azure function to do HTML to Pdf conversion and am getting the following error in Azure function logs:

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.20.0\32bit\wkhtmltopdf' is denied.

Code on the functions is pretty basic:

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
        
var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(req.BodyHtml);

return new FileContentResult(pdfBytes, "application/pdf")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
    };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

The same code works in Visual Studio debug locally

error stack:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
> while executing function: HTMLtoPdfConverter  --->
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program
> Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.20.0\32bit\wkhtmltopdf' is
> denied.    at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath,
> Byte[] securityDescriptor)    at
> System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)    at
> NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.EnsureWkHtmlLibs()    at
> NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdfInternal(WkHtmlInput[]
> htmlFiles, String inputContent, String coverHtml, String
> outputPdfFilePath, Stream outputStream)    at
> NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(String htmlContent,
> String coverHtml, Stream output)    at
> NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(String htmlContent,
> String coverHtml)    at
> NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(String htmlContent)
> at
> Showcast.Azure.Functions.HTMLtoPdfConverter.Run(HtmlToPdfConverterArgs
> req, ILogger log) in
> C:\Showcast\Code\showcast.web\Showcast.Azure.Functions\HTMLtoPdfConverter.cs:line
> 26    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(Object
> instance, Object[] arguments) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line
> 52    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeWithTimeoutAsync(IFunctionInvoker
> invoker, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, CancellationTokenSource
> timeoutTokenSource, CancellationTokenSource
> functionCancellationTokenSource, Boolean throwOnTimeout, TimeSpan
> timerInterval, IFunctionInstance instance) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line
> 581    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx
> instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger,
> CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line
> 527    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx
> instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry
> instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line
> 306    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx
> instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry
> instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line
> 352    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance
> functionInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line
> 108

Comment: please share your whole code to help you better

Comment: [FunctionName("HTMLtoPdfConverter")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HtmlToPdfConverterArgs req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
            var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(req.BodyHtml);

            return new FileContentResult(pdfBytes, "application/pdf")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
            };
        }

Comment: what does HtmlToPdfConverterArgs contains in your case

Comment: it's a class containing 3 string properties

Comment: your function works locally? or you are getting this error in local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.20.0\32bit\wkhtmltopdf' is denied.

indicates that you use "NReco.PdfGenerator" nuget which includes wkhtmltopdf binaries for Windows and it tries to extract them on the first `GeneratePdf` method call but default location for this binaries (which is usually app's folder with DLLs) is not accessible for write.

To fix this it is enough to specify another location for wkhtmltopdf binaries, in most cases temp folder is accessible for write and can be used for this purpose:

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
htmlToPdf.PdfToolPath = Path.Combine( Path.GetTempPath(), "wkhtmltopdf" );
```

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, thank you for the help. With the above change, I am not getting an error on Azure but the generated PDF has just a few black squares instead of the actual text that I passed to it.

Comment: @Angelo Black squares may indicate that your HTML template uses font that is missed on Azure Function environment. If this is standard Windows font (like Arial) it might be possible that your HTML may use non-English unicode letters and default system font simply don't have glyphs for these letters.

Comment: you are right. it was the missing fonts. I scaled up the Azure Function app to a higher plan and it works great now. Thank you very much.